# OpenGL Android, I had a 3D spinning cube and it has disappeared

Tags: android, opengl-es

I had a 3D cube spinning around as I wanted, but after trying (and failing) to integrate a react-native view into my app I wanted to start over. I control + Z'd my way back to what I thought was the original file, but now my cube is gone. The background color is still the same as it was before. I assume I accidentally deleted a line of essential code, and I know how fragile OpenGL can be. Anyways, is can anyone help me figure out why cube is gone? Here is the chunk of code that I modified, am I missing anything??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView gLView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1;  // Choose any value

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }
    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.
    gLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(gLView);
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final MyGLRenderer renderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        renderer = new MyGLRenderer();

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(renderer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you need to do before setRenderer() is calling [setEGLConfigChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView#setEGLConfigChooser(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), which seems missing in that code.

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

:

setRenderer(renderer);
```